# calling an array from an html input value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to call an array in javascript from the input the user selects on the webpage..

```
<select id="weekdayOptions">
            <option>Monday</option>
            <option>Tuesday</option>
            <option>Wednesday</option>
            <option>Thursday</option>
            <option>Friday</option>
        </select>
```

javascript is ...

```
var selectDay = document.getElementById('weekdayOptions').value;

var Monday = ["hi" , "hello" , "test"];

var Tuesday = ["hi" , "hello" , "test"];

var Wednesday = ["hi" , "hello" , "test"];

var Thursday = ["hi" , "hello" , "test"];

var Friday = ["hi" , "hello" , "test"];

alert(selectDay[2]);
```

the values of the array are only the same for an example, in my code they are different, but what i am trying to do is call the array for the weekday chosen by the input of the user, hope i explained this clearly, any help is great, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a string (e.g. "Monday") to reference a variable name, and that won't work (without `eval`, which you should avoid). You'd be better off having the days of the week be object keys.

```js
var options = document.getElementById('weekdayOptions');
var weekdays = {
  Monday: ["hi" , "hello" , "test"],
  Tuesday: ["hi" , "hello" , "test"],
  Wednesday: ["hi" , "hello" , "test"],
  Thursday: ["hi" , "hello" , "test"],
  Friday: ["hi" , "hello" , "test"]
};

options.onchange = function() {
  var selectDay = this.value;
  alert(selectDay + ': ' + weekdays[selectDay][2]);
}
```

```html
<select id="weekdayOptions">
  <option>Monday</option>
  <option>Tuesday</option>
  <option>Wednesday</option>
  <option>Thursday</option>
  <option>Friday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would recommend:

**HTML**

```
<select id="weekdayOptions">
    <option value="M">Monday</option>
    <option value="T">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="W">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Th">Thursday</option>
    <option value="F">Friday</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var days = {
    M: ['monday 1', 'monday 2', 'monday 3'],
    T: ['tuesday 1', 'tuesday 2', 'tuesday 3'],
    W: ['wednesday 1', 'wednesday 2', 'wednesday 3'],
    Th: ['thursday 1', 'thursday 2', 'thursday 3'],
    F: ['friday 1', 'friday 2', 'friday 3']
}

var daySelect = document.getElementById('weekdayOptions');
daySelect.onchange = function() {
    alert(days[this.value][2]);
};
```

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oag5tgmg/).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the following. *Take care so that you assign a default value in case the user leaves it on Monday without touching the selectbox.*

[**JSFIDDLE here**](https://jsfiddle.net/s6j6eqL6/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="weekdayOptions">
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
    <option>Thursday</option>
    <option>Friday</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var selectDay = document.getElementById('weekdayOptions'); 
var selOptionArray = ["MONhi" , "hello" , "MONtest"]; // Default for Monday: If the selectbox is left unchanged there is no value assigned to the array.

selectDay.onchange = function(){

    switch(selectDay.value){
        case 'Monday':
            selOptionArray = ["MONhi" , "hello" , "MONtest"];
            break;
        case 'Tuesday':
            selOptionArray = ["TUEhi" , "hello" , "TUEtest"];
            break;
        case 'Wednesday':
            selOptionArray = ["WEDhi" , "hello" , "WEDtest"];
            break;
        case 'Thursday':
            selOptionArray = ["THUhi" , "hello" , "THUtest"];
            break;
        case 'Friday':
            selOptionArray = ["FRIhi" , "hello" , "FRItest"];
            break;
        default:
            selOptionArray = "";
            break;
    }

     alert(selOptionArray[2]);
}
```